# Regex expression: Expression for Extracting Date is not working with Series object throws an error

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, regex-group

I'm trying to extract date from text data. The expression is valid and works fine when I checked in regex101 website. But when applied to the data it throws an error "**ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups**". My sample text is ["Mar-20-2009", "Mar 20, 2009", "March 20, 2009", "Mar. 20, 2009"," Mar 20 2009"] inputted as a pandas series object.

```
df2 = pd.Series(["Mar-20-2009", "Mar 20, 2009", "March 20, 2009", "Mar. 20, 2009"," Mar 20 2009"])
df2.str.extractall(r'(?:\d{2} )?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]* (?:\d{2}, )?\d{4}')
```

It doesn't match with any date in actuality my **expected output** is ["March 20, 2009", "Mar 20 2009","Mar 20, 2009"].
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXpTC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your string in extractall in parenthesis like this:

```
df2 = pd.Series(["Mar-20-2009", "Mar 20, 2009", "March 20, 2009", "Mar. 20, 2009"," Mar 20 2009"])
df2.str.extractall(r'((?:\d{2} )?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]* (?:\d{2}, )?\d{4})')
```

Output:

```
                      0
  match                
1 0        Mar 20, 2009
2 0      March 20, 2009
```

Here you are creating one capture group that match all those regex expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @scott Boston

Answer (score 1):

All of your parenthesized expressions are non-capture groups (?:) so the error message is correct.  If you want to capture an expression, don't use the ?:  just put it in parenthesis.  As is, the pattern will match, but no groups will be captured.